# Error message when phonegap run android

Tags: android, cordova

I want to run my app on device. but i can not run it because of this message alert during i use this command phonegap run android.

```
 This is the message shows during i run android in phonegap. 



 c:\project\resource_map_phonegap>phonegap run android
    [phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
    [phonegap] using the local environment
    [phonegap] compiling Android...
    [ReferenceError: a is not defined]

    module.js:340
        throw err;
              ^
    Error: Cannot find module './spawn'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (c:\project\resource_map_phonegap\platforms\android\co
    rdova\lib\build.js:23:15)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
       [error] cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found to fix this is to remove the Android platform and re-add it (make sure to copy the Android folder somewhere else first, just in case):

```
cordova platform remove android

cordova platform add android
```

You should be able to build fine after that. Just make sure you add any Android plugins or native code back in that may get wiped.